# Apache Flink Kerberos configuration in custom deserializer for Hortonworks Schema Registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kerberos, jaas

I'm trying to connect to Hortonworks Schema Registry from a custom deserializer for a Kafka topic using Apache Flink.

I am able to read messages from secured Kafka by setting *sasl.jaas.config* property on Kafka consumer. But when I add a custom deserializer that uses Hortonworks Schema Registry to get the deserialization schema, the service response with 401 HTTP Code: Authentication required. I've Kerberos enabled on this service.

What I 've tried:

Set java.security.auth.login.config on deserializer implementation:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/path/to/jaas.conf");
```

Launch application with dynamic Java options:

```
flink run [...] -yD env.java.opts="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf" myApplicatio.jar
```

Setting env.java.opts in *flink-conf.yaml*:

```
env.java.opts: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf
```

Neither of these options worked for me.

The content of the jaas.conf to authenticate against HW Schema registry is:

```
RegistryClient {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   principal="flink@mydomain.com"
   keytab="/etc/security/keytabs/flink.keytab"
   useKeytab=true
   useTicketCache=true
   renewTicket=true
   serviceName="flink";
};
```

Could someone help on this?

Update: I whing something is missing in the server since a curl request shows Internal server error on Spenego negotiation, The traceback on the server logs is:

```
ERROR  [2019-10-10 10:49:46.099] [dw-26402 - GET /api/v1/schemaregistry/schema] c.h.r.c.GenericExceptionMapper -  Got exception: [NotFoundException] / message [HTTP 404 Not Found]
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:323)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:45)
        at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at com.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.webservice.RewriteUriFilter.doFilter(RewriteUriFilter.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at com.hortonworks.registries.auth.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:595)
        at com.hortonworks.registries.auth.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:553)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:241)
        at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:724)
        at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try appending your `RegistryClient` section to the Kafka-specific section, in the file specified by  _`sasl.jaas.config`_?

Comment: To get more visibility about what JAAS is doing under the covers -- and what the web client library is doing about the HTTP 401 challenge  -- add some debugging flags like `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​,logincontext` and `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true`

Comment: Note that the initial HTTP 401 is **expected**, that''s the way SPNego works -- the web client library should manage this "challenge" by sending the same exact request with an extra header containg a Kerberos auth token _(or failing that, a NTLM token, but Hadoop services don't support that legacy Microsoft thing)_. Try contacting the Schema registry with `curl --negotiate --user :` in debugging mode (e.g. `--trace-ascii -`) to understand how SPNego works.